# Can I use CASE of IF statements to conditionally run different SELECT statements?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to run two different queries depending on a condition.

This is done in Logi Studio. The VariableFromLogi is a string literal. I don't just want to get this to work. I would like to gain a better understanding of pl/sql. The oracle says that CASE statements return s, but all the examples I've see are ones where it return values.

```
CASE WHEN 'VariableFromLogi' = '' THEN
(SELECT "InvoiceID" 
FROM "DataManagement_Sys"   
WHERE "InvoiceID" = '1111')
ELSE
(SELECT "InvoiceID" 
FROM "DataManagement_Sys"   
WHERE "InvoiceID" = 'VariableFromLogi')
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
END CASE
```

I get an invalid SQL statement error

Comment: On a side note: `FETCH FIRST ` makes little sense without an `ORDER BY` clause. You are returning arbitrarily picked rows from the intermediate result set.

Comment: As to your code: You are right, can use `CASE WHEN` in PL/SQL. But PL/SQL is a programming language. It doesn't perform a query and return data as SQL does. Inside PL/SQL you can use queries (and store their results in arrays for instance). And in SQL you can reference PL/SQL functions that return arrays of data. (If you are interested in this, you can look up PL/SQL pipelined functions.) This is why your example cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the two queries return the same columns, you can write a query for this.

In your example:

```
SELECT invoiceid
FROM datamanagement_sys
WHERE invoiceid = COALESCE(:variablefromlogi, 1111);
```

More general:

```
SELECT invoiceid
FROM datamanagement_sys
WHERE invoiceid = 1111 AND :variablefromlogi IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT invoiceid
FROM datamanagement_sys
WHERE invoiceid = :variablefromlogi;
```

As you can see, you can just glue different queries (that return the same columns) together with `UNION ALL` and you use your variable to have only one of the queries return values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are quite a lot of things you can do (and even more you can not do).

Code you posted can be rewritten as (disregard mixed case)

```
select invoiceID
from datamanagement_sys
where invoiceid = case when variableflomlogi is null then '1111'
                       else variableflomlogi
                  end;
```

or - even better (just the `WHERE` clause)

```
where invoiceid = nvl(variableflomlogi, '1111');
```

This is a simple case. Depending on how a real problem looks like, query would change.